# Insert Future Chosen Date Into Database PHP

Tags: php, database, date, post, insert

For school I have to make this simple working To-Do website. I have basically finished everything but I can't seem to get 'date' working.

What I mean with that is that I want the user to be able to choose an expiration date. For example, it's 18 april 2012 now and a user is making a task and wants to have it done before 22 april 2012. That should be the expiration date and the user should be able to choose that date. I don't even need the task to be deleted when the time finishes but just that it shows on the task page that that's the expiration date.

I have absolutely no clue on how to do this.. I was thinking about input fields for d-m-Y
and making it simple by posting it something like this

`$date = $_POST['date'];`

If someone knows where I can find a premade script for this I would surely appreciate it a lot as it's been bugging me for days now.

Comment: For simplicity, Google 'javascript date pickers', there's thousands to choose from.

Comment: Yes, but it's made for mobile and desktop. Date pickers won't work for mobiles

Comment: Have a regular desktop version, and a separate one for mobile: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want something dead simple:

Markup:

```
<input type="date" name="date" />
```

PHP:

```
try {
    $dt = new DateTime($_POST['date']);
    $dateString = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    // If we get here, the user provided an invalid date
}

// Do something with $dateString here (like put it in the database)
```

Note that the `date` input type will gracefully degrade to a `text` input for devices/browsers that don't support it.  You can optionally implement some kind of JS datepicker on top of this if you want to, but it's not necessary.